# UI Automator doesn't start in OSX

Tags: android, macos, appium, android-uiautomator

```
yogevabergel [~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin] $ ./uiautomatorviewer
-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/yogevabergel/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/yogevabergel/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Any help? Nothing in the internet about it.

Answer (score 0):

First, check you set properly system variables like JAVA_HOME & ANDROID_HOME and that tools are in place, easy way is to use `appium-doctor` for this:

```
npm appium-doctor -g
appium-doctor --android
```

And fix any error you get.

It can be also that you miss some component in android-sdk-tools:

1. Launch Android Studio
2. `Configure` => `SDK manager`
3. On SDK Tools tab check status for Platform-Tools & SDK Tools, update if possible

Comment: Seems like it all fine, both in doctor, and Android Studio, all installed.

Answer (score 0):

Which java version are you running?
I hit the same issue with Java v.10, installed Java v.8, updated ~/.bash_profile with

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

and it helped.